# Can't call Flash (Swf) method from Javascript within QWebView

Tags: javascript, qt, flash, qwebview

I have:

- Swf-file, that a) makes one of its method available to the outer world through ExternalInterface.addCallback; b) calls predefined outer world method through ExternalInterface.call;
- html-page, where this Swf-file resides. There are two javascipt methods in this html: one for calling Swf-published-method and one for being called by swf;
- Qt-app, that loads this html-page through QWebView->QWebPage.

When I load this html-page in FireFox everything works ok: Swf can be called from javascript and vice-versa. However within Qt-app only swf can call javascript method, but not vice-versa. Calling swf method fails with the following message printed on javascript console: "Error calling method on NPObject".

Any ideas how to make Qt-app behave like FireFox, i.e. to make it possible to call Swf from javascript? Any help will be appreciated,

Backgrounds:

- Qt 4.6.2;
- Kubuntu 10.04;
- Swf was built with Flex 4;
- Swf is local trusted.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed problem by myself.

The original code for loading html-page was like this:

```
QFile html(<theHtmlPageFileName>);

html.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

m_page->mainFrame()->setContent(html.readAll());
```

The rewritten variant:

```
m_page->mainFrame()->load(<theHtmlPageFileName>);
```

In latter variant everything works fine.

Btw: Under Windows first variant works too.